# is there any way to allow/block remember password prompt of browser using c#/Java Script/Response headers.

Tags: c#, http, response, response-headers

Is there any response header to access browser password manager disable/enable password prompt of browser? 
like interpret access to third party cookies using P3P header?

Answer (score 0):

No.

You can try to disable autocomplete and layout your password forms so they don't look like sign in (i.e. name and password on separate pages/forms) - this may prevent browser to suggest to remember passwords. Also even if you convince vanilla version of browser there are plenty of plugins for each browser that would remember password/other form fields just to help people visiting such "friendly" sites.

Note that any attempts to make entering password to be harder generally end-up with simpler passwords/passwords written on sticky notes. Make sure you understand drawbacks of forcing users to re-enter passwords.